# sql запрос. вывести строку по максимальному значению ячейки

Tags: sql

Дана таблица

```
planGraf
```

с полями

```
regNum
inn
xml
vNum
```

по такому запросу `SELECT * FROM dbo.planGraf WHERE regNum='01213213545447' OR inn='546488421'` выводит 2 строки с разными vNum.
Как написать заброс чтобы выводил строку по максимальному vNum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1
   T.[regNum]
  ,T.[inn]
  ,T.[xml]
  ,T.[vNum]
FROM dbo.planGraf AS T
WHERE regNum='01213213545447' OR inn='546488421'
ORDER BY vNum DESC
```